# Symfony2 retrieve the parameter values from URL

Tags: php, symfony, url, parameters

when i try to get the parameter from url its returning nothing

Here is my url : `http://localhost/myapp/web/dailydata/payment/amount/1000`

**Here is my symfony script :**

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
.
.
public function MyAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $amount = $request->request->get('amount');
    echo 'Amount ='.$amount;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: If you have .../{amount} in your route definition then $request->attributes->get('amount') or just function myAction($amount)

Comment: Thanks `$request->attributes->get('amount')` works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
.
.
public function MyAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $amount =$request->attributes->get('amount'); //replace this line in above code
    echo 'Amount ='.$amount;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Glad it is working.  Just as a side note, consider injecting the request: MyAction(Request $request)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a proper route in you `routing.yml` file like this:

```
my_action:
    path:      /dailydata/payment/amount/{amount}
    defaults:  { _controller: <bundle>:<controller>:My }
```

If you don't specify which part of the route is a parameter you can't access it from the action. Replace the various gaps (proper URL, bundle and controller) where necessary.